# jQuery targeting all list elements instead of only one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem where my drop-down list is toggling the entire set of `li` elements. I was just wondering how I could change my jQuery to target the *first child ul* of the parent, in this case the `span` element I clicked on.

Is there a simple way to fix this problem? I attached a JSFiddle below, also not entirely sure why list has a giant left margin but that seems trivial.

http://jsfiddle.net/4yJuc/24/

**The HTML**

```
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
    <dt><a href="#"><span>COUNTRIES</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Brazil<img class="flag" src="br.png" alt="" /><span class="value">BR</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">France<img class="flag" src="fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Germany<img class="flag" src="de.png" alt="" /><span class="value">DE</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">India<img class="flag" src="in.png" alt="" /><span class="value">IN</span></a></li>

        </ul>
    </dd>

        <dt><a href="#"><span>PLANETS</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">EARTH<img class="flag" src="br.png" alt="" /><span class="value">BR</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SATURN<img class="flag" src="fr.png" alt="" /><span class="value">FR</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MARS<img class="flag" src="de.png" alt="" /><span class="value">MR</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PLUTO(JK)<img class="flag" src="in.png" alt="" /><span class="value">PL</span></a></li>

        </ul>
    </dd>


</dl>
<span id="result"></span>​
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

            $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
                $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
            });

            $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).html();
                $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
                $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
            });

            function getSelectedValue(id) {
                return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
            }

            $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                var $clicked = $(e.target);
                if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
            });


            $("#flagSwitcher").click(function() {
                $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
            });
        });
```

Comment: please include your (simplified) markup and code here, not just a pointer to a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `click` handlers you can't just use class specifiers - that's why your actions are affecting *every* matching element.

You'll need to traverse the DOM tree (i.e. `.parent()`, `.child()`, etc) to find the related elements that you want to modify.

For example in this handler:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
});
```

your presumably wish to show the `dd > ul` element that follows the `<dt>` that contains the clicked `<a>`:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('dd').children('ul').first().toggle();
});
```

although that said (per comments), if your HTML markup stays as it is you can simplify it as follows, since there's only one `<ul>` and the `<dd>` always follows the `<dt>`:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().children().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering what the syntax is for targeting the first child UL element of a parent span class.

Comment: In this case, $(this).parent().next('dd').child('ul').first().toggle() can be simplified to $(this).parent().next().children().toggle()

Comment: @BartoszGórski indeed, it can be simplified - I thought it worth showing the explicit selectors